# nginx transparent reverse proxy keepalive Error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Creating nginx transparent proxy. As a result of checking the curl, it is successful.
However, http keep-alive does not works normally.

```
client ---> nginx ----> Server (GET)  
client <--- nginx <---- Server (200 OK)  
client ---> nginx ----> Server (GET failed)
```

nginx log
failed (98: Address already in use) while connecting to upstream

nginx.conf file

```
upstream proxy {
    server proxy;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
    server_name myhomepage.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_pass http://proxy;
    }

}
```

**$remote_port must be included.**

https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/

I think this problem occurs because it is managed by pool when connecting to nginx server.